# HAXM Installer (Android Studio for Mac)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

"Unable to install Intel® HAXM
HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac.
Please file a bug against Android Studio."

This comes up when I try to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by manually installing HAXM, which can be downloaded from the Github repository:  https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases  To be on the safe side, I first uninstalled Android Studio and removed the `~/Library/Android` folder, and then manually installed HAXM `IntelHAXM_7.7.0.mpkg` which is inside the `IntelHAXM_7.7.0.dmg` that I downloaded (supra).

Comment: I tried but it was not working, I upgraded my OS to big sur and now everything is fine